# How is called the segment that is drawn from an angle and divide the opposite segmet into two equal parts?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

My english is not very good and I want to know what is this called in english and why it's called so?

Comment: [Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)): from [middle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=median).

Comment: I think you are asking about an angle of a *triangle* and the side of that triangle *opposite* to that angle.  Rewording the Question might help many Readers.  If you like I will undertake to edit it for you, assuming I have understood the Question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segment joining a vertex of a triangle to the center of the opposite edge is called the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)).

It has a latin origin, and [Merriam Webster gives its etymology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/median) as “medianus” meaning “*in* the middle” from “medius” meaning “middle”. The [OED link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=median) Mauro provided in a comment writes “medianus” to mean “*of* the middle” and “medius” to mean “*in* the middle”. I'm not certain myself about these fine translation details, but the general idea is the same. (If you want more details on the translation nuances, ask on [Latin SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com/).)